# CKEditor: In IE9, scrolling in CKEditor fires blur event

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, ckeditor, blur

In IE9, on scrolling using the scrollbar in the CKEditor, it throws blur event. I need to ignore this blur event when it is fired due to scrolling. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Any help is appreciated.

Scrolling is done inside the editor and not in the page that contains the editor. It is done by using the mouse to click on the scrollbar and then drag it up/down.

In my use-case, blur event is listened to save the editor text and close it. So, when the user clicks on scrollbar, it fires blur event and the editor is closed. On the contrary, in Firefox and Chrome, the editor does not lose focus on clicking on the scrollbar.

Comment: Please add comment on what you do, what you have tried. the code, and language (in the tags).

Comment: In what way do you scroll? Scrolling can mean many different things. Are you scrolling within the editor or the page that contains the editor? Using the mouse wheel or clicking on a scrollbar? Pageup? Usually in any case it's not possible prevent that event. I suggest that you look at what requirement you actually have, why is blur a bad thing, what is the need it that not blurring solves - and think if your solution is really the way to go. I would imagine that there is some other solution to be found.